# Convert an array into an object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that I access like this:

```
$item['id'];
```

What can I do to the array to access it like this instead?

```
$item->id
```

Comment: $item->name isn't a reference to an associative array, you already have that.... it's an object reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that array is coming from a database, such as mysql you can fetch objects instead of arrays with [mysql_fetch_object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php)() or set the flag PDO::FETCH_OBJ if you are using PDO.

Maybe it is not relevant to you however ...

Answer (score 11):

Use this code:

```
$item = (object) $item;
echo $item->property;
```

The `->` syntax is for objects, not associative arrays. You can use the `(object)` [cast operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting) to cast an array into an object of the class `stdClass` though.

Answer (score 2):

Cast it to (a stdClass) object:

```
$item = (object) $item;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it into an object

```
$item = (object) $item;
echo $item->id;
```